# dropDownList set by JS a then handle indexChanged Event

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

I have a problem with my DropDownList control. I have three valus "select", "test1", "test2". First I manually choose "test2" value then I have to set "select" value by JS

```
  var ddlTestData = document.getElementById("<%= testDataDDL.ClientID %>");
  ddlTestData.selectedIndex = 0;
```

It works fine but when I choose "test2" value my `TestData_IndexChanged` event doesn't start.

thanks in advance for Your help.

Comment: can you post your Html code part?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like you are really looking for an ASP.Net answer -- classic ASP does not have a `ClientId` property.

With that assumption, is your IndexChanged event wired to your testDataDDL drop down list control (you need to set that in your code) -- is it `"OnSelectedIndexChanged"`?  Also you may need to set `AutoPostBack="True"`.

Comment: I had it in my code. testDataDDL.SelectedIndex = 0; It doesn't work too.